# Last digits of a Power of 3 using digits 0, 4, 8 not counting the last

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for a pattern continuation in the last $x$ digits (except the final digit) of $3^n$ using only multiples of 4 (0, 4, 8). This is narrowed down to 01, 03, 09, 81, 83, 89. What are the next possible patterns?

Comment: The last two digits of $3^{4n}$ are $01,81,61,41,21$. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: I am excluding any last ending digits starting from the tens place that is not 0, 4, or 8. So that would leave 01, 41, 81, from there: 001, 401, 801, 041, 441, 841, 081, 481, 881. For the last 4 digits: 0001, 4001, 8001, and so on... The examples start from 0000...1, 0000...3, 0000...9,